# Ruby on rails files setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, web, ruby-on-rails-5

I have some doubts about the folders on which I should put the public files.
We got at the root path a folder called **public** and some other folders in **app** (rails 5.0.1 for me), let me show you the ones which sound strange for me:

- **app/assets/ (images | javascripts | stylesheets)**
- **app/views/pages**

After reading multiple tutorials and existing public projects, I saw that some people put his web template in **public** (*js, css and images included*).
Yet, in my case, because of I have seen it few times too and found it logic, I have put my template in **assets** separating my js, sass (in my case) files, and images in the folders already created by the RoR generator.

Additionnal, it seems logic for me to put my files in assets because my main layout gonna take my template files in assets with the framework default API. The following line works for me and gonna load my *app/assets/stylesheets/* **app.css.scss** file

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'app', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Hope someone could explain what's the better way, I'm beginner with Rails, thanks.

Comment: Put your js, sass, and images in the assets directory, this adds them to rails asset pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**app/assets/**

This is where you put custom assets (images, js/css scripts that you own and custom to your application)

**vendor/assets/**

This is for third party libraries that you use in your app (carousel js plugin, etc)

```
.
├── app
│   ├── assets (custom assets specific to your app)  
├── public (static-files like error pages, favicon, etc which does not change much)
├── vendor
│   └── assets (third party libraries that your app uses)
```

**Precompiled Assets**

Add all the paths to your assets (images, js/css files) used in your application in assets precomile path in `config/initializers/assets.rb` (application.css and application.js are included by default)

All the assets when precompiled with

```
bundle exec rails assets:precompile
```

This generates **public/assets** directory with all the assets configured in your precompile path as readily servable static assets which are then served to your application responses.

Comment: Ok so vendor/assets should contains my lib ? such as Foundation or Bootstrap ?

Comment: Thanks really helpful answer! Another question, I dont use the default application.css in assets/stylesheets, I use my proper app.css.scss (for image-url in my css code). Is it bad or not ? I dont use requires etc.. I dont understand exactly how it works. Does Rails compile itself my scss files ?

Comment: That's fine .. you don't need to use application.css if you don't want to .. Rails precompiles `.scss` files to CSS with the help of `gem 'sass-rails'` .. Include it and bundle if you don't have it already

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for it. But atm it seems he can read it, I can see my website working with .css.scss. Seems strange

Comment: Aight, it seems that sass-rails is already installed by default ;)